# I just don't understand

Tags: variables, python-3.x

Write   code    defining    a   variable    named   “difficultyLevel”   such    that if it  were added  to  the very    top of  the program below,  the program would   output  the 
string `“Q1 – Easy\nQ2  – Medium\nQ3    – Easy\n”`

```
for question,   level   in  difficultyLevel:
            print(question, “-“,    level)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
difficultyLevel = [("Q1", "Easy"), ("Q2", "Medium"), ("Q3", "Easy")]
```

I ignored some of the bizarre spacing in the given output. To better understand this, read about [unpacking tuples](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples#Packing_and_Unpacking)